# Read a file of numbers into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, file-io

There are similar questions online but they haven't provided an adequate response. I am trying to write 3 random numbers to a file called "mydata.txt" using an ofstream object and extract those 3 numbers from "mydata.txt" using an ifstream object. Here is my code:

```
ofstream myOFile {"mydata.txt"}; //open a file using the ofstream default constructor
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++) {
    myOFile << (rand() % 100) << "\n"; //write random numbers from 0 to 99 to myOFile
}

ifstream myIFile {"mydata.txt"}; //open the same file using the ifstream default constructor
int nums;
vector<int> numsV;
while(myIFile >> nums) { // myIFile >> nums is false when end of file is reached
    numsV.push_back(nums); //add the numbers to a vector of ints called numsV
}

cout << numsV.size() << endl; //Why does this output zero?

for(int i : numsV) {
    cout << i << endl; //Why is nothing ouputted here?
}
```

When I look at the physical file mydata.txt on my computer, I can see 3 random numbers on the document, meaning that the write to a file worked. Why can't I read the file?

Comment: You probably need to close the file after you finish writing to it.

Comment: Next time, search the internet for "c++ read file numbers vector".  This issue has been discussed many times on StackOverflow.  Or change your title to "What's wrong with my reading of a file".

Comment: @user253751 Thank you! This worked. I assumed that the file would implicitly close after the for loop, but it was still in scope.